# How to override OmniFaces default validation/conversion error messages?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I'm using some OminFaces (1.8.1) validators as for example,

```
<o:validateAllOrNone components="a b c d" showMessageFor="someComponent"/>
```

If at least one of the specified fields is left blank in which case it displays a default message like as shown below.

> a, b, c, d: Please fill out all or none of those fields

I want to override such error messages in resource bundles especially to get a localized message.

Unlike JSF, no resource bundles are found in OmniFaces. Is this still possible to override this error message somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `message` attribute for that.

```
<o:validateAllOrNone components="a b c d" showMessageFor="someComponent"
    message="#{i18n['some.bundle.key']}" />
```

where `i18n` is the `<resource-bundle><var>` of your resource bundle.

Indeed, the OmniFaces `ValidateMultipleFields` components do not support providing those messages via `<message-bundle>` without the need to declare the `message` attribute everytime.

---

Coincidentally, 3 days ago I've for the upcoming OmniFaces 2.0 [committed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/49a16f7cedcb33784d04970cac5bb47190199eaa) [several changes](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/06e8ec74104622fcc7afaf5ba53d813c7305e923) in those validators which should make it possible to override the default message via `<message-bundle>` when using the component type as key. So in case of [`<o:validateAllOrNone>`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/component/validator/ValidateAllOrNone.html) which has a [component type](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/component/validator/ValidateAllOrNone.html#COMPONENT_TYPE) of [`"org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateAllOrNone"`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/constant-values.html#org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateAllOrNone.COMPONENT_TYPE), you should be able to override it in the resource bundle as identified by `<message-bundle>` as follows:

```
org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateAllOrNone = {0} all or none!
```